# Object not passed correctly to managed bean - for commandButton action parameter inside primefaces subtable

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, java-ee-6, managed-bean

Im using primefaces 3.3.1, mojarra 2.1.3, netbeans 7.0.1.

```
<p:dataTable id="approvalchainstable" var="department" value="#{viewApprovalChain.wfdepartments}">
   <p:columnGroup type="header">  
       <p:row>
          <p:column colspan="4" headerText="#{bundle.DepartmentNameFieldLabel}" />  
       </p:row>
       <p:row>  
          <p:column headerText="#{bundle.PostNameFieldLabel}"/>  
          <p:column headerText="#{bundle.ItemCountLabel} #{bundle.ApprovalLevelNameFieldLabel}"/>
          <p:column headerText="#{bundle.ViewLabel}"/>  
          <p:column headerText="#{bundle.LabelDelete}"/>    
       </p:row>  
   </p:columnGroup>  
   <p:subTable var="approvalchain" value="#{department.wfApprovalchainCollection}">  
       <f:facet name="header">  
          #{department.wfDepartmentName}   
       </f:facet>  
       <p:column>  
          #{approvalchain.idWfPost.wfPostName}  
       </p:column> 
       <p:column>  
          #{approvalchain.wfApprovalchainLevel}  
       </p:column> 
       <p:column>  
          <h:link outcome="/viewApprovalChainDetails" value="#{bundle.ViewLabel}">
            <f:param name="idWfApprovalChain" value="#{approvalchain.idWfApprovalchain}"/>
          </h:link>
       </p:column> 
       <p:column>  
          <p:commandButton value="#{bundle.LabelDelete}" 
                           title="Delete"
                           icon="ui-icon-trash"
                           action="#{viewApprovalChain.removeOneApprovalchain(approvalchain)}">
          </p:commandButton>
       </p:column> 
   </p:subTable>     
</p:dataTable>
```

And here's the ViewScoped managed bean method -> the parameter passed from the action call above resolve to null in managed bean. Therefore I got NullPointerException error.

```
    public String removeOneApprovalchain(WfApprovalchain wfapprovalchaintoremove) {
    try {
        LogController.log.info("Removing approval chain flow for application " +
                wfapprovalchaintoremove.getIdWfApplication().getWfApplicationName() +
                " applicable for " + wfapprovalchaintoremove.getIdWfPost().getWfPostName() +
                " in " + wfapprovalchaintoremove.getIdWfDepartment().getWfDepartmentName());
        wfApprovalchainFacade.remove(wfapprovalchaintoremove);
        LogController.log.info("Reloading department names for the select one box");
        wfdepartments = wfDepartmentFacade.selectAll();            
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        LogController.log.fatal(ex.toString());
    } finally {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Im pretty confident i've done it right. But why do the wfapprovalchaintoremove object parameters always resolve to null? Why does the parameter not passed correctly inside primefaces subtable? I tried that inside datatable without subtable and it's working correctly. Please help, your help is very much appreciated.

Comment: What scope are you using on your backer? Request?

Comment: Hi @catfish backing bean is ViewScoped

Answer (score 0):

Well what you do is OK, it should be working, I did a test and parameter was passed correctly from `p:subtable`. Maybe there is something wrong in your `p:dataTable` construction?

Comment: Hi @michal777 are you using same versions of mojarra and primefaces?

Comment: No, Primefaces 3.2 and Mojarra 2.0.4.

Comment: Something may be broken in yout p:dataTable definiotion, simplify it as much as possible and do the test if its not working you can paste it here I can try to reproduce problem in my enviroment

Comment: Thanks @michal777. I've put my datatable coding edited into my question above. Please help.

Comment: kk I'll do some testing today